# How Can I Mitigate My Learning Disabilities And Improve My Abstract-Reasoning Abilities?

Tags: self-learning, disability

I am seeking advice for understanding how I can improve my abstract reasoning abilities. More specifically, I would like to understand how I can revise my reasoning abilities in mental areas such as spatial-discernment and logical-discernment.

For the entirety of my lifespan, I have suffered from great difficulty understanding mental abstraction.

When I tried to understand elementary, geometrical concepts, for example, I frequently had to stop concentrating on visualizing the material, because trying to mentally construct and connect the actual structures was an agitating process.

I have tried to visualize logical patterns in the same manner as during my spatial manipulation, and I experienced the same sort of difficulty.

Though I have improved somewhat in those regards, I can usually only perform very simple discernment such as using the area/perimeter of a rectangle/square/triangle. As for my logical-reasoning, I can partially understand simple predicates.

However, I would like to improve this ability for my own use. I would like to be able to not only visualize geometric/logical problems and decompose them into their components, yet also construct different, viable "solutions" and deductions from those components.

At this moment, I am trying to use jigsaw puzzles and strategy board games such as Chess to progress towards that goal. However, my disabilities are interfering with that process.

As for the actual disabilities, I am not entirely aware of the names. I often develop "shifting thoughts" and become confused during mathematical symbolism/operations(And certain other subjects as well). Once the confusion occurs, the agitation usually follows.

In any case, thank you for reading the question.

Comment: FWIW, you can try the online mathematics exercises that I have created: http://www.public-domain-materials.com/folder-student-exercise-tasks-for-mathematics-language-arts-etc---autocorrected.html

Comment: @Anonymous Exchangist I must confess that I have always been skeptical about "learning disabilities" and that I have always tended to believe that it is the educational materials that are the primary culprit. You can find my own educational materials at (http://freemathtexts.org) where you can also find my email address. If you find some of them worth trying to read, perhaps you will let me know what your specific difficulties with the stuff are. If nothing else, it would help me but, in any case, I would be quite ready to elaborate on your questions.